Positivity of the first fundamental form
my question is how to prove that the first fundamental form is positive definite.
I know what the first fundamental form is, that is the restriction of the scalar product to all tangent spaces, that is $$I(X,Y)=\langle X,Y\rangle$$ for two tangent vectors $X,Y.$
I know that one condition for the positive defineteness is $x^{*}Tx>0,x\neq 0$ but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.
The first fundamental form matrix is I believe this,
$$
\begin{align*}
&I(\frac{df}{du},\frac{df}{du})~~~~I(\frac{df}{du},\frac{df}{dv})\\
&I(\frac{df}{dv},\frac{df}{du})~~~~I(\frac{df}{dv},\frac{df}{dv})
\end{align*}
$$

The scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is positive definite, i.e., for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $$v\cdot v > 0\text{ if }v \ne 0.$$  Therefore, its restriction to any subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is positive definite. In particular, its restriction to a tangent plane is positive definite.

Yes but the question is how to prove that the Matrix is positive definite.

Use the polarization identity
